# SQL sum with condition field='x'

Tags: sql, sum, conditional-statements

I have two tables to register `TESTS` and `GRADES`

Table `TEST (id_test, id_person, retry)`

Table `GRADE (id_grade, id_test, id_question, grade)`

It's possible that a person make a second test, in that case, retry would be char 'Y' (for yes)
Now I need to sum all the grades grouped by person.

The problem is that When I group by person the sum comes from both test retry `'N'` and retry `'Y'`.

But if a person has a retry test, I want to sum only this one.

Example

if `TEST (id_test, id_person, retry)` has values

```
(1,1,'N')
(2,1,'Y')
(3,2,'N')
```

and `GRADE (id_grade, id_test, id_question, grade)` has values

```
(1, 1, 1, 4)
(2, 1, 2, 4)
(3, 1, 3, 4)
(4, 2, 1, 5)
(5, 2, 2, 5)
(6, 2, 3, 5)
(7, 3, 1, 7)
(8, 3, 2, 7)
(9, 3, 3, 7)
```

I want the sum for person #1 be 15 (5+5+5) and not 27 ( (5+5+5) + (4+4+4) ). And for person #2 who does not have a retry the sum is 21. How can I get a list of person and it's grade with sql?

Comment: you can put where clause.

Comment: This wouldn't be very hard if you had a retry value that identifies all tests to sum... or if the retry column was integer (then you could MAX it). But as is how are you going to identify the test that is to be counted? Can a test be retried only once? What value do you have in the retry column in case you have multiple retries? Which is the last retry?

Comment: where are you getting the values 15 and 27 from?

Comment: Please add details. What RDBMS are you using? What logic can be used to identify the test to sum? The one with the highest id or something based on the retry columns.

Comment: ORACLE. The sql should return a list of all person and the sum of it's grades. BUT as it's a list by person. If a person has a retry test, the sum should get only the grades of this one. Need also consider that there are people who did not make a second test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select id_person,sum(b.grade) from 
    (
        select id_person,max(id_test) testid  from test
        group by id_person

    )a
inner join GRADE as b on a.testid = b.id_test
group by id_person
```

[Working Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4ed51/13)

Comment: and what if there is none? i.e. the test was passed on the first try and never retried

Comment: hmmmm, hope user wants what u have asked.

Comment: Yes a test can only have one retry. But I can't use this clauses in Where because there are other people who did not made a retry.

Comment: Almost there. I edited my ask with more detail. Maybe if I use a case clause in select would work?

Comment: you can take latest attempt by user & them go for sum grade of it. I have updated answer & also demo.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you cannot realy group by person. You have to calculate the sum grouping by test (which is easy), and decide which tests to keep and which to discard (which is the hard part, especially since your specs are not very clear).

The basis for this query is:

```
SELECT t.id_test, t.id_person, t.retry, SUM(g.grade) AS sum_grade
FROM test  t
JOIN grade g ON g.id_test=t.id_test
HAVING <some_filter_condition>
```

The condition here depends a lot on some thing you have not told us.

If you want the last test of each person, then you can use this:

```
SELECT t.id_test, t.id_person, t.retry, SUM(g.grade) AS sum_grade
FROM test  t
JOIN grade g ON g.id_test=t.id_test
HAVING t.id_test=(
  SELECT MAX(t2.id_test)
  FROM test t2
  WHERE t2.id_person=t.id_person)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there are many methods to solve this problem. I could provide you an idea.
1. Get the sum for person with retry=Y => result A
2. Get the sum for person where id_person NOT EXISTS in result A
3. Join together
4. Done

Comment: This is more like a comment than an answer ;)

Comment: Sometimes, a thinking process is more useful than a complete source code.

Comment: Yes... I agree... and what is SO comments are for ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
   SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY id_person ORDER BY retry DESC) AS rn
   FROM   TEST 
)
SELECT SUM(grade) AS Total
FROM   MyCTE T
       JOIN GRADE G
           ON T.id_test = G.id_test
WHERE rn = 1
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b1ec8/3)**

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the points I'd select all retried tests and all tests that don't have a retry.

First one is straight forward:

```
SELECT id_test FROM test WHERE retry = 'Y';
```

And the second one isn't that complicated either:

```
SELECT id_test FROM test t1 WHERE retry = 'N' and NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM test t2 WHERE t1.id_person=t2.id_person AND t2.retry='Y');
```

Combined with a UNION you get all test ids:

```
SELECT id_test FROM test WHERE retry = 'Y'
UNION
SELECT id_test FROM test t1 WHERE retry = 'N' and NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM test t2 WHERE t1.id_person=t2.id_person AND t2.retry='Y')
```

which gives you ids 2 & 3. Calculating the sum from there can be as simple as:

```
SELECT id_test, SUM(grade) FROM grade WHERE id_test IN (
    SELECT id_test FROM test WHERE retry = 'Y'
    UNION
    SELECT id_test FROM test t1 WHERE retry = 'N' and NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM test t2 WHERE t1.id_person=t2.id_person AND t2.retry='Y')
) GROUP BY id_test;
```

edit:
Just for completeness the query for id_person, SUM(grade):

```
SELECT id_person, SUM(grade) FROM grade g JOIN (
    SELECT id_test, id_person FROM test WHERE retry = 'Y'
    UNION
    SELECT id_test, id_person FROM test t1 WHERE retry = 'N' and NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * FROM test t2 WHERE t1.id_person=t2.id_person AND t2.retry='Y'
    )
) t ON t.id_test = g.id_test
GROUP BY id_person;
```

Comment: BTW don't forget indices. Guess one over (retry, id_person) should lower the query costs.

Answer (score -1):

```
select sum(g.grade) 
  from 
      TEST t,GRADE g 
  where 
      t.id_test = g.id_test 
  and 
       t.id_person = 1 ...
```

Comment: that will make sum be 27 and not 15, which is what I want

Answer (score -1):

select SUM(grade),id_person,id_question from

TEST natural join GRADE

group by id_test

where id_test=2;